# cant set my location on flutter google maps

Tags: flutter, maps

I am newbie in flutter, I am trying to set my location as the center point of the map that the app draw on the screen

I am using statefulwidget as the root of my app and add this code :

```
class MyMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyMapState();
  }
}

class MyMapState extends State<MyMap> {
  GoogleMapController googleMapController;
  LocationData currentLocation;
  LocationData distinationLocation;
  Location location;

  @override
  void initState() {
    location = Location();
    setInitSourceAndDestination();
    super.initState();
  }
  setInitSourceAndDestination() async {
    currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),);

    return GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) => googleMapController = controller,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
      compassEnabled: true,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
    );
  }
}
```

But there are a problem I can not solve:

- the map is drawn in the screen before currentLocation is set 
  I tried setState and the problem has not been solved.

How can I make the app draw the map after setInitSourceAndDestination method finish excuting?
What make me confused is that the code at this form the build method will be excuted before setInitSourceAndDestination method finished, but if I add setState and change the currentLocation value inside it to rebuild the screen I noticed that setState executed before build function but it still dont show my location

Comment: did you check location permission in your device?

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check the state. If the state is null, then draw a loading indicator. If not null, draw the maps

it can be look like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  double lat;
  double long;
  LatLng _pickedLoc;

  Future _getLocation() async {
    LocationData location = await Location().getLocation();
    setState(() {
      lat = location.latitude;
      long = location.longitude;
    });
  }

  _selectLocation(LatLng location) {
    _pickedLoc = location;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getLocation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: lat == null || long == null
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                zoom: 16,
                target: LatLng(lat, long),
              ),
              onTap: _selectLocation,
              onCameraMove: (object) => {debugPrint(object.target.toString())},
              markers: {
                Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId("m1"),
                  position: _pickedLoc,
                )
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```